# Rscript does not load methods package, R does -- why, and what are the consequences?

Tags: r, rscript

Just saw this:

```
$ Rscript -e "sessionInfo()['basePkgs']"
$basePkgs
[1] "stats"     "graphics"  "grDevices" "utils"     "datasets"  "base"

$ R --vanilla --slave -e "sessionInfo()['basePkgs']"
$basePkgs
[1] "stats"     "graphics"  "grDevices" "utils"     "datasets"  "methods"
[7] "base"
```

The `methods` package seems to be always available when running `R`, but not with `Rscript`. I suspect that this is to gain performance, but are there any practical implications besides the obvious? I'm asking because of a [funny bug](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/645) that is triggered by the presence or absence of the `methods` package.

Comment: You can always explicitly load a package by adding `library(methods)` to your .Rprofile

Comment: related thread on r-devel: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/advise-on-Depends-tp4678930p4679079.html

Comment: `?Rscript` tells you why it omits the methods package, "The default for `Rscript` omits `methods` as it takes about 60% of the startup time."

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: Thanks, this explains the "why". I have only consulted `man Rscript`.

Comment: If you are a package writer, it means that your package needs to `Depends: methods` in the DESCRIPTION file (see the comment by Chambers in the thread cited by @GSee), and `import("methods")` in the NAMESPACE file -- probably 'best practices' anyway.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19468506/271616)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to `?Rscript` the methods package isn't loaded because, "The default for Rscript omits methods as it takes about 60% of the startup time."

Comment: This tiny speedup is a horrible reason to do something so dastardly.  It causes various R code to run differently in unpredictable ways under `R` and `Rscript`.  On my machine, `echo 7 | R` takes 0.15 seconds, and `Rscript -e 7` takes 0.07 seconds.  Hardly something worth the spooky-action-at-a-distance it causes.

Comment: ...and sorry for commenting on an old question & answer, but 3 scientists in my group just shared horror stories of losing days at a time discovering this behavior, so I wanted to come put a comment on the first applicable SO question that Google found for me. =)