# R CMD BATCH vs Rscript

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am having a problem running a .r file.

If I run it with

```
R CMD BATCH filename.r
```

then everything is fine but if I run the same file with

```
Rscript filename.r
```

then I get the following error message:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'is' not found
Calls: amelia -> amelia.default -> sapply -> match.fun
Execution halted
```

Does anyone know why?

By the way, I want to use Rscript instead of R CMD BATCH because I want to be able to pass some parameters to my filename.r.

Comment: Or checkout this Q/A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680462/rscript-does-not-load-methods-package-r-does-why-and-what-are-the-consequen

Comment: Thanks a lot! Should I delete this question?

Comment: It's up to you. If you had a hard time finding the answer and you think this question has better keywords so that others may find the answer more easily, then leave it up.