# Setting python version from command line

Tags: python, r, anaconda, gdal, rscript

I am trying to run an R script from the command line using `Rscript`. The R script calls some python code and works fine when run interactively. However, when I call it from `Rscript` I get some errors with `gdal`. I believe the errors are related to python 3 vs 2. For example, running the following command in an interactive R session:

`system("python --version)`

yields

> Python 2.7.9

while running the "same" command from the shell:

`$ python --version`

yields

> Python 3.5.1 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.

How can I point my `$ Rscript "foo.R"` calls to python 2.7.9?

Comment: Can't you use shebang in your Python code to tell which version should be used? Something like this: `#!/bin/env python2` or `#!/bin/env python3`. This should be added to the beginning of your Python code.

Comment: use `python3` explicitly as the command name

Comment: How did you launch the interactive R sessions? I suspect that it has an different PATH environment variable than the shell. Can you print the PATH environment variable from the command line and from the R session?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala @Dataman I am calling some stock `gdal` scripts. I don't think I want to be editing them (specifically `gdal_polygonize.py`)

Comment: How do you launch the R session?

Comment: RStudio... but I don't see how that matters.

Comment: It matters because it is receiving a different set of environment variables. How do you launmch RStudio?

Comment: Ubuntu task-bar launcher

Comment: Can you type `which python` and `whereis python` and tell us what the results are?

Comment: The other option might be to set your `PYTHONPATH` using: `export PYTHONPATH=*path_to_the_desired_python_version*` to the desired version.

Comment: Can you see why you get what you get from your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to insert a call to the `methods` library in my R script and create/load a python 2 environment using the command:

`$ conda create --name python2 python=2`
`$ source activate python2`

See:
[Rscript does not load methods package, R does -- why, and what are the consequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680462/rscript-does-not-load-methods-package-r-does-why-and-what-are-the-consequen)
and
http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke either `$ python --version` or `$ Rscript -e 'system("python --version")'` from the shell command line, you are operating in a Python virtual environment, perhaps one created by `virtualenv`. Specifically, you are executing `/home/foo/miniconda3/bin/python`

When you run `system("python --version")` from RStudio, you get the system default version. Specifically, you are executing `/usr/bin/python`.

> > How can I point my `$ Rscript "foo.R"` calls to python 2.7.9?

That depends upon how you entered your virtual Python environment. If it was one created by `virtualenv`, simply deactivate it:

```
$ deactivate
$ Rscript -e 'system("python --version")'
2.7.9
```

EDIT: You appear to be using virtual environments created by [miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html). If that is the case, you can use the system default Python by editing your PATH environment variable. How you edit your PATH depends upon how long you want your change to have effect.

- For your change to lost for only a single command, try this:

  ```
  $ PATH="$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e s,:/usr/local/sbin,,)" Rscript -e 'system("python --version")'
  ```
- For your change to last the duration of a single shell session, try this:

  ```
  $ PATH="$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e s,:/usr/local/sbin,,)"
  $ python --version
  $ Rscript -e 'system("python --version")'
  ```
- To permanently change your PATH, edit the file $HOME/.bashrc appropriately. You will need to start a new terminal session for this to have affect.

Comment: You are such an excellent editor, if you know what I mean? ;)

Comment: I understand that the paths are different. However, I have no idea what `virtualenv` is.  

`$ virtualenv`
> The program 'virtualenv' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install virtualenv

Comment: @jsta -- That means that you didn't use virtualenv to create your virtual python environment. How did you create /home/foo/miniconda3, and how did you cause it to be first on your PATH? However you did that, that is what you have to undo.